# java implementation of Kruskal's algorithm - very high run time on large instance

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime

I'm testing it on an the smallest of the DIMACS challenge 9 instances: New York
(more here: http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/challenge9/download.shtml)

instance size: 264,346 vertices and 733,846 edges

my run time is around 260 seconds with Kruskal and with Prim's algorithm it's usually just a few seconds.

I am using path compression and union by rank and I can't figure out why my run time is so high and if it's just a combination of the algorithm and instance.

a couple snippets:

```
public void union(UnionFindNode<T> setOne, UnionFindNode<T> setTwo){
        UnionFindNode<T> rootOne = find(setOne);    
        UnionFindNode<T> rootTwo = find(setTwo);    
        //union by depth (rank)
        if(rootOne == rootTwo){
            return;
        }
        if(rootOne.getRank() < rootTwo.getRank()){
            rootOne.setParent(rootTwo);
        }
        else if(rootOne.getRank() > rootTwo.getRank()){
            rootTwo.setParent(rootOne);
        }
        else{
            rootTwo.setParent(rootOne);
            rootOne.setRank(rootOne.getRank() + 1);
        }
}

public UnionFindNode<T> find(UnionFindNode<T> start){
        //get parent of current node
        UnionFindNode<T> parent = start.getParent();
        //if not root
        if(parent != start){
            //compress path to root
            start.setParent(find(parent));
        }
        //return final parent 
        return start.getParent();
}
```

UnionFindNode is just an object with T data, UnionFindNode parent, and int rank as fields.

Comment: This union-find code could be improved, but it's not bad enough to be a real problem. It works fine. Your problem must be in the code you didn't post.

Comment: Oh man I feel dumb. I was using get(i) on a linkedList of edges which had a length of 1.4 million.